# Renaming Android apk Programmatically

Tags: android

Is it possible to rename a Android apk file extension programmatically without a rooted device? The goal is to disable a application from starting up, is this possible?

Comment: before or after the user has installed the application?

Answer (score 0):

With one limited exception, the Android security model prevents one application from altering files belonging to another, so the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to disable applications using [PackageManager.setApplicationEnabledSetting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setApplicationEnabledSetting%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) but you'll probably need to call it from an application signed with the same key as the app to be disabled.

Comment: i believe this won't allow me to modify another applications setting.

Comment: Indeed, this is a security restriction for obvious reasons.